# Removing "size" attribute from Wordpress posts

Tags: html, css, size

I'm trying to remove the size attribute from my Wordpress posts but I can't figure out how to do it. The images are blurry even though they are enough large for the container. If you look at my website, http://www.kashmaizat.se/ and if you inspect an image, you can see the "size" attribute and it says sizes="(max-width: 660px) 100vw, 660px". I don't want this to be there at all, I want the image to be a width of 100% not 660px. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

This is what I see when i'm inspecting the code on my website:

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-374" src="http://i0.wp.com/www.kashmaizat.se/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/photo-1448085792726-2755f17091fa.jpg?resize=660%2C459" alt="photo-1448085792726-2755f17091fa" srcset="http://i0.wp.com/www.kashmaizat.se/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/photo-1448085792726-2755f17091fa.jpg?w=1000 1000w, http://i0.wp.com/www.kashmaizat.se/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/photo-1448085792726-2755f17091fa.jpg?resize=300%2C209 300w, http://i0.wp.com/www.kashmaizat.se/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/photo-1448085792726-2755f17091fa.jpg?resize=768%2C534 768w" sizes="(max-width: 660px) 100vw, 660px" data-recalc-dims="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function disable_sourceset($sources) {
 return false;
}
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset', 'disable_sourceset' );
```

Removes Wordpresses (fairly) new responsive images functionality, and may be what you require.

Comment: I added this to my functions.php but it didn't make any change =(

Comment: Solved it! I had jetpack installed and "photon" activated so basically that was the problem. But thanks anyways!

Comment: So the function worked? If so, could you please mark it correct :)

Comment: Vote from me, works perfectly, should be marked as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta', '__return_null' );
```

Simply add in function.php.